# date extracted from database, how to write date in jsp page?

Tags: java, html, jsp

why i am not able to write date of birth extracted from database into jsp page ?

```
<html>
    <body>
         <%@ page import="java.sql.*"%> 
         <%@ page import="java.util.Date"%>
         <%
              Statement stmt=null;
              Connection con=null;
              try {  
                   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
                   con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb","root","");   
                   stmt=con.createStatement(); 
              }
              catch(Exception e) {
                   out.write("<br>database connection problem");
              }
              ResultSet rs = null;
              Date dob= null;
              try {
                   rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from registrar1 where id='"+id+"';");  
                   while(rs.next()) {
                        dob = rs.getDate(3);
                   }
              }
              catch(Exception e) {

              }
         %>
         Date of Birth : <% out.println(dob);  %><br>
     </body>
 </html>
```

the following error is given by eclipse id :

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - dob cannot be resolved to a 
     variable

Comment: Can you complete the error message given to you by the compiler?

Comment: "dob cannot be resolved to a variable" , this is complete error msg